# Regex to find out fields which are having non ascii character in python

Tags: python

i have data of thousand records which i read line by line . Each line has some fields and their value but field names contain a non ascii character, below is the example of such a record :

```
|              |   | X:720                      | N°227: Done
```

where X and N°(non ascii character) are fieldnames and 720,227 and "Done" are field values which i have to extract.
 These fields are optional which may exist or may not .
Now I have to check whether these fields exist in line or not and if it exists then what is its  value(for example X field is having value 720 and N° is having value 227 and "Done")
Please let me know how to do this using regex in python ,is there any another way to do this in python?

Comment: You need to seriously rework your question. The punctuation and grammar render it largely unreadable.

Comment: Add more examples with input and desired output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes regex is good for such thing, sometimes `split()` and other string method will be easier. It is up to you to chose:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import re
RE_TXT = re.compile(r'\|\s*X:(\S+)\s*\|\s*N\D*(\d+):\s*(.*)$')
txt = '|              |   | X:720                      | N°227: Done'
rx = RE_TXT.search(txt)
if rx:
    print(rx.group(1))
    print(rx.group(2))
    print(rx.group(3))

print('-' * 20)

# other way without regex, but with more complicated logic:
arr = [s.strip() for s in txt.split('|')]
if arr[3].startswith('X:'):
    print(arr[3].split(':')[1])
    N, state = arr[4].split(':')
    N = N[3:]
    state = state.strip()
    print(N)
    print(state)
```

As for regexp:

- `\s*` is zero or more white characters
- `\S+` is one or more non white character
- `\d` is for digits
- `\D` is for non digits
- `.` means any character
- `r` before string means "raw" string so you do not need to escape backslash

Comment: RE_TXT= re.compile(r"\s*(?:(X)\s*:\s*(\d+))?\s*\|\s*(?:(N\D*(\d+)\s*:\s*(.*)))")

Comment: i have used above regex to validate whether field is present or not and if present then what is its value but it is working fine if both field is present and if X field is missing but for N° field missing condition it fails where is the problem?

Comment: If you will build more logic with various conditions then use non-regexp solution. Regexp is good for all or nothing solutions, but more complicated and probably very cryptic will possibly work. Maybe add more examples with input and desired output to your question.